# Embeding PySide/PyQt widget into Qt/C++ application

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a C++/Qt application which should have its GUI extensible with modules. Extending should be simple and versatile. I am just checking a concept - is it possible to have this main C++/Qt application that would execute a Python/PySide/PyQt script which would create a QWidget (or derived class) instance and embed this widget into the main C++/Qt application?

Is there any working snippet to demonstrate the feasibility of this task? I.e. how to create and embed the widget? How to pass signals between the application and the widget?

Comment: Sure I have... and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but in case someone else is face the same issue, I will try to give a useful answer.

I think it's possible. In the following example, I create a QApplication and QMainWindow in c++, embed a python interpreter, and then, on the python side, I create a QPushButton which I add to the main window.

Try this out:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"

class PythonQt
{

public:

  PythonQt()
  {
    char name[] = "test";
    Py_SetProgramName(name);
    Py_Initialize();

    std::string code =
        "from PySide import QtGui\n"
        ""
        "all_widgets = QtGui.QApplication.instance().allWidgets()\n"
        "window = None\n"
        "for widget in all_widgets:\n"
        "    if str(widget.objectName()) == \"main_window\":\n"
        "      window = widget\n"
        "      break\n"
        ""
        "def message_box():\n"
        "    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Test', 'Hello!', \ 
                      QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)\n"
        "    QtGui.QApplication.instance().quit()\n"
        ""
        "button = QtGui.QPushButton('Press Me')\n"
        "button.clicked.connect(message_box)\n"
        "window.setCentralWidget(button)\n"
        "window.move(600, 300)\n"
        "window.show()";

    PyRun_SimpleString(code.c_str());
  }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow win;
  win.setObjectName("main_window");

  PythonQt python_code;

  a.exec();
}
```

The python script is written here in a string to have everything in a single file, but you could of course read it in from a .py file.

Object ownership could be an issue though, as shown in the link given by Trilarion.

Comment: It worked like charm using `PySide` built for `Qt4` on Debian 9 (Stretch)

Comment: Hi Francois, I had some trouble running similar code in qt5, would you read my comment under George Vinokhodov‘s answer and tell me what was my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. PySide/PyQt are wrappers around C++/Qt. That means you create C++ objects and Python wrapper objects and somehow the wrapper objects kind of refer to the C++ objects. This works one way as far as I know.

But you want the other way. Basically a wrapper around Python objects (which themselves are wrappers around C++ objects) to use in C++. I don't think PySide/PyQt are ready for thise. However it is possible to [embed Python in other languages](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

Also see [How to shoot yourself in the foot.](http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html) about the pitfalls of communication between C++/Qt and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here is adapted for QT5 version of Francois answer:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <iostream>

class PythonQt
{

public:

  PythonQt()
  {
    Py_SetProgramName(L"/path/to/executable");
    Py_SetPythonHome(L"/path/to/python-home");
    Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag = true;
    Py_Initialize();

    std::string code =
        "import sys\n"
        "print(sys.path)\n"
        "from PySide2 import QtGui\n"
        "from PySide2 import QtWidgets\n"
        ""
        "all_widgets = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().allWidgets()\n"
        "window = None\n"
        "for widget in all_widgets:\n"
        "    if str(widget.objectName()) == \"main_window\":\n"
        "      window = widget\n"
        "      break\n"
        ""
        "def message_box():\n"
        "    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Test', 'Hello!', \
                      QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)\n"
        "    QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().quit()\n"
        ""
        "button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Press Me')\n"
        "button.clicked.connect(message_box)\n"
        "window.setCentralWidget(button)\n"
        "window.move(600, 300)\n"
        "window.show()";

    PyRun_SimpleString(code.c_str());
  }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow win;
  win.setObjectName("main_window");

  PythonQt python_code;

  a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hi George, I had some trouble running your code. I am working on python 3.7 and qt 5.15. The problem is, the value I get from `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()` is `None`, although we have already created one in the C++ part. If I create a QApplication instance in the python side, the c++ part and python part will be isolated. We won't find a object `main_window`. Am I doing something wrong?