# Embed a PySide6/PyQT5 Widget into a QT C++ application?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

While this question has already been answered at [Embeding PySide/PyQt widget into Qt/C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553642/embeding-pyside-pyqt-widget-into-qt-c-application) . I could not reproduce the code because I did not have OPs functions and more importantly the post is 8+ years old and QT has developed a lot since then, especially when it comes to Python.

I need a method to have my PySide widget called by C++ QT main window/application and essentially work as a QColor, I need to call it and it will return a value just like how QColor works.

Simplified explanation:

I need to call my PySide widget in C++ QT like this

---

a = CustomPySideWidget()

---

I need to be able to recieve data to the variable a, this data can be returned as a simple string so the data type will be C++ compatible.

Is there any methods to do this via PySide or PyQT?

Thank you for any help.